# Mount cement counter top

Tags: concrete, cabinets, countertops, custom-cabinetry

I made an outdoor cabinet out entirely out of cedar. The counter top was made of  cedar 1x4s originally but that proved to be a bad idea at preventing water ingress. Since then I've made a custom counter top out of cement.

**How can I attach my cement counter top to my wooden cabinet?** given that:

1. my cabinet is movable (on wheels)
2. I sometimes grab the counter top to move the cabinet

I have Lexel caulk on hand which would serve a double purpose of sealing the bottom of the counter top to the frame to prevent water ingress, however I don't know if that alone is enough to hold it in place given the movable nature of the cabinet.

I'm also afraid to drill in to it to put anchors as it is only 1.5in thick (rebar re-enforced).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to secure the concrete top to your cabinet is to use construction adhesive that is rated for bonding with both wood and concrete. The concrete and wood should be clean and dry before attempting to do the bonding.

After the adhesive has dried the top will be pretty much permanently bonded to the wood of the cabinet. If you want to have the top be removable you could consider gluing some wood blocks or strips to the concrete that are positioned in such manner that you can add screws through the side of the strip into the cabinet structure. Removing the top would then be a process of taking out these screws and then lifting off the top with its strips/blocks still attached.

Comment: good idea. ill place the counter top on the cabinet to position it properly, cut out some small blocks of extra wood i've got lying around and use them to mark the inside position, take it off, glue it. put it back, and screw it to the sides. thanks!

Comment: You could also pre-mount the blocks to the cabinet structure and then just apply the glue to the tops of the blocks and then carefully set the top in place. If there is some concern of getting the adhesive also on the cabinet as well as the blocks then apply blue painters tape to the top edges of the cabinet that you do not want the glue to squeeze out onto.

Comment: I like the block idea that way if there is a change later it will be easy.